# Bulk renaming using regex in Php

Tags: php, regex

I have a folder in a server with a lot of images and I would like to rename some images. Images that contain `(1` example:
`112345(1.jpg to 112345.jpg`. How can I do this using regex in PHP? I have to mention that my knowledge of PHP is very limited and it's the only language that can effectively do the scripting.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what text you want to change in the file names? Giving one example is not robust enough to understand the replacement operation you want to do. Do you want to remove `(1` from every file in the directory? Remove `(1` from the end of the file name before the file extension? Being more specific will help us to better answer your question and create a better question overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_match('/\(1/', $entry)` will help you.

Also, you need to pay attention to "what if the file has a duplicate after the rename".

```
$directory = "/path/to/images";

if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != '.' && $entry != '..') {

            // Check "(1"
            if (preg_match('/\(1/', $entry)) {

                // Rename file
                $old = $directory . '/' . $entry;
                $new = str_replace('(1', '', $old);

                // Check duplicate
                if (file_exists($new)) {
                    $extension = strrpos($new, '.');
                    $new       = substr($new, 0, $extension) . rand() . substr($new, $extension); // Basic rand()
                }

                rename($old, $new);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: The way that you use regex makes it so wide open that you might as well use strpos. Your regex will match any file with `(1` anywhere, which is the same thing as what strpos will do but far much cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only remove some substring from images names you can do this without regex. Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function to replace substring to empty string.
As example:

```
$name = "112345(1.jpg";
$substring = "(1";
$result = str_replace($substring, "", $name);
```

Comment: I believe it's actual files, not just strings with filenames.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scandir and preg_grep to filter out the files that needs to be renamed.

```
$allfiles = scandir("folder"); // replace with folder with jpg files
$filesToRename = preg_grep("/\(1\.jpg/i", $allfiles);

Foreach($filesToRename as $file){
    Echo $file . " " . Var_export(rename($file, str_replace("(1.", ".", $file));
}
```

This is untested code and in theory it should echo the filename and true/false if the rename worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

Only use regex for this if you need to assert the position of the substring, e.g. if you have filenames like `Copy (1)(1.23(1.jpg` a simple string replacement will go wrong.

```
$re = '/^(.+)\(1(\.[^\\\\]+)$/';
$subst = '$1$2';
$directory = '/my/root/folder';
if ($handle = opendir($directory )) { 
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {     
        $newName = preg_replace($re, $subst, $fileName);
        rename($directory . $fileName, $directory . $newName);
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

The regular expression used searches for the part before and after the file extension, put the pieces into capturing groups, and glue them together again in the `preg_replace` without the `(1`.